# Проект мониторинга процессов в сети c#

Tags: c#, процесс

Доброго времени суток всем, подскажите реализацию мониторинга процессов, которые используют интернет, т. е. допустим есть процесс который использует интернет, мне его нужно найти и запретить доступ в firewall с помощью C#.

Comment: Можно запретить всем, тогда будет точно известно, что ни один не использует.

Comment: Обычно файервол настраивают так: запрещают все, а потом открывают порты только нужным сервисам и программам. Вы же хотите наоборот, но такой подход заведомо ведет к просчетам в настройках и "дырявой" защите.

Comment: @Bulson делают и так и так, в зависимости от требований.

Comment: Сильно зависит от того, что вы считаете под "использовать интернет". Заливка на ftp, обращение к сетевой шаре - всё это виды использования интернета? Вопрос слишком общий. Это и о том, как отловить сетевую активность (скажем https://stackoverflow.com/q/17026204/5752652 ) и о используемых протоколах о том, какие адреса являются своей подсетью, а какие интернетом. Не стоит такой крупный проект пытаться утрамбовать в один вопрос, он может решаться слишком разными вариантами.